# Split comma separated list, sort and compare - output the difference - KSH

Tags: unix, compare, ksh, string-comparison

I'm working on a problem in KSH, and need to take two comma separated lists and compare them, then output the differences.

**Example input 1:**
apple, banana
**Example input 2:**
apple, banana, kiwi

**Output:**
kiwi

I assume I will need to put the lists into arrays and compare each string in list 1 to list 2, through a loop.

```
for fruit in $fruits
do
if [[ fruit[1] == fruit1[1] ]]
then
echo "fruit is the same"
else
echo "fruit is not in the list. difference found."
echo $fruit
fi
```

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking for complement of two lists:

```
$ a="1,2,3,4,5"
$ b="2,3,4,5,6"
$ echo $a,$b | tr , "\n" | sort | uniq -u
1
6
```

or, the same, but passing lists separetely (e.g. if you need different preprocessing):

```
$ sort  <(echo $a | tr , "\n") <(echo $b | tr , "\n") | uniq -u
1
6
```

Comment: You sort a and b. So the example is more clear with `a="3,1,2,5,4"`.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution could be:

localhost > `cat file1`

apple,banana,kiwi,apple

localhost > `cat file2`

apple,banana,jewel,potato

The eaisest solution is :

`cat file1 | tr , '\n' | sort` > file3

`cat file2 | tr , '\n' | sort` > file4

`comm -3 file3 file4`

**Output:**

apple

jewel

kiwi

potato